# why change the html element's id , the click bind with the old id also run

Tags: javascript, jquery

html代码：

```
<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
<li><a href="#" id="add1">录入1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="add2">录入2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="add3">录入3</a></li>
</ul>

<button type="button" class="addinfobtn" id="addRoomInfo">addinfo1</button>
```

js代码：

```
$("#side-menu a").click(function(){
 switch($(this).attr("id")){
   case "add1":
     $(".addinfobtn").text("addinfo1").attr("id", "addRoomInfo");
     break;
   case "add2":
     $(".addinfobtn").text("addinfo2").attr("id", "addServiceInfo");
     break;
   case "add3":
     $(".addinfobtn").text("addinfo3").attr("id", "addMenuInfo");
     break;
 }

$("#addRoomInfo").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

result: I change the .addinfobtn id ,but when I click the button, the click function run, and console the id that is already changed. why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve,really hard to understand from you question?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you trying to say, but events are binding to the button itself, not the particular ID. Changing the ID of the button won't affect the click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector is used for the registration of an event and is only used at the time the event is registered, not when the event is fired.

To avoid this problem use delegated event handlers, attached to a non-changing ancestor of the dynamic elements.

e.g.

```
$(document).on("click", "#addRoomInfo", function(){
  console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

This evaluates the filter at click time, not when the event was registered, so is a useful technique for any dynamically changing selectors.

Document is the default if nothing is closer, or more convenient, but do not use body for delegated events as it has a bug to do with styling that means mouse events may not fire.

It seems a little unusual to change the text and ID of the elements. You might be better off authoring all the elements and just hide and show them as required. This simplifies maintenance.

Comment: `do not use body for delegated events as it has a bug to do with styling that means mouse events may not fire` Any sample to share? Thx

Comment: @A.Wolff: easy to reproduce. If body's children have absolute positioning then body gets a calculated height of 0 and mouse events stop bubbling to it. Found this by accident last year so always suggest document as the better option "just in case" as any speed difference is negligible.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this issue and cannot see why an event bubbling to `document` level wouldn't to `body` one as `body` is part of `document`: http://jsfiddle.net/206LLmj9/ It would be interresting if you can refind your last year issue. But don't lose your time on it, i'm just interrested about it and completly out of topic here, so all my apologies

Answer (score 1):

The click handler is bound immediately to the DOM node. The selector is not evaluated on each click.

So the selector finds all elements that match, then binds the click handler on those elements. The selector is never used again.

Comment: While this answers the "why?" part it does not provide a solution to the problem.

Comment: The question was about why, not about a solution? The intent of the code seems unclear to me, there is no way to know what a good solution would be to some problem not mentioned in the question, which is likely why it has a vote of -3 now? We could all guess what problem the author is trying to solve. But it could be an example to get to know jquery and event binding better?

Comment: I realise the question may be badly worded, but you specifically say *why* it does not work, so you understand the technical problem, but you do not suggest how to avoid the problem. SO is about technical solutions and there were several you could have suggested. This would have been more suited as a comment as all I am saying. :)